# Vagrant create box Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I have some problem whith Vagrant (vagrantup.com). I want create box (for launch Vagrant) Ubuntu Server 12.04 whith my setting. I already set setting Ubuntu (in Oracle VM VirtualBox). But I don't know how compilate *vdi file to *box file.

Answer (score 5):

You can follow instruction from Vagrant documentation [Creating Base Boxes](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html#creating_base_boxes) or use [VeeWee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) to do stuff for you.

[VeeWee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) is the tool to easily build vagrant base boxes or kvm,virtualbox and fusion images.

Or maybe box you want to create is already on [Vagrantbox.es](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)?